# Integration with substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I would like to take the integral of the following function:

$$ \int_{0}^{x} \frac{1.4}{{2\sqrt{0.04+1.4u}}\; (1.2 -\sqrt{0.04 + 1.4u})} du$$

I try the substitution $$w = 1.2 - \sqrt{0.04+1.4u},$$ and I got the result as follows:

$$-\ln|1.2-\sqrt{0.04+1.4x}| + \ln|1.2-\sqrt{0.04}|$$
Is this correct?

Comment: The answer is correct. There are limits on the $x$ for which this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Another approach :**

Let $y=\sqrt{0.04+1.4u}\;\color{blue}{\Rightarrow}\;dy=\dfrac{1.4}{2\sqrt{0.04+1.4u}}du=\dfrac{0.7}{y}du$, then the integral turns out to be
$$
\int_{u=0}^{x} \frac{1.4}{{2y}\; (1.2 -y)}\cdot \frac{y}{0.7}dy=\int_{u=0}^{x} \frac{dy}{1.2 -y}.
$$
Now, let $v=1.2 -y\;\color{blue}{\Rightarrow}\;dv=- dy$, then
$$
\int_{u=0}^{x} \frac{dy}{1.2 -y}=-\int_{u=0}^{x} \frac{dv}{v}=-\ln\left|1.2-\sqrt{0.04+1.4x}\right|,
$$
since $\ln\left|1.2-\sqrt{0.04}\right|=\ln1=0$ and your answer is of course **correct**.